# how to set different texts to labels with tags in a scrollview in swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uiscrollview, uilabel

```
homeScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 
homeView.bounds.size.height)

for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    scrollBtnLbl1 = UILabel()
    scrollBtnLbl2 = UILabel()
    scrollBtnLbl3 = UILabel()

    scrollViewStartHeight = scrollViewStartHeight+50

    scrollBtnLbl1.frame = CGRect(x: (screenWidth-450)*1/4, y: scrollViewStartHeight+180, width: 150, height: 30)

    scrollBtnLbl1.text = "about worldcup"
    scrollBtnLbl1.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-Regular", size: 15)
    scrollBtnLbl1.textColor = UIColor.black
    scrollBtnLbl1.textAlignment = .center
    scrollBtnLbl1.tag = i


    homeScrollView.addSubview(scrollBtnLbl1)


    scrollBtnLbl2.frame = CGRect(x: (screenWidth-450)*2/4 + 150, y: scrollViewStartHeight+180, width: 150, height: 30)

    scrollBtnLbl2.text = "top goals"
    scrollBtnLbl2.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-Regular", size: 15)
    scrollBtnLbl2.textColor = UIColor.black
    scrollBtnLbl2.textAlignment = .center
    scrollBtnLbl2.tag = i

    homeScrollView.addSubview(scrollBtnLbl2)

    scrollBtnLbl3.frame = CGRect(x: (screenWidth-450)*3/4 + 300, y: scrollViewStartHeight+180, width: 150, height: 30)

    scrollBtnLbl3.text = "top goals"
    scrollBtnLbl3.font = UIFont(name: "Metropolis-Regular", size: 15)
    scrollBtnLbl3.textColor = UIColor.black
    scrollBtnLbl3.textAlignment = .center
    scrollBtnLbl3.tag = i

    homeScrollView.addSubview(scrollBtnLbl3)

    scrollViewStartHeight = scrollViewStartHeight+300

}
```

I have 9 labels  in `scrollview` which is `homescrollview` and I want to give different texts to each of them. I have assigned tags to each of it, but I don't know how to access those labels with tags. any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them by `viewWithTag` method:

```
if let lbl = self.view.viewWithTag(1 /*your UILabel tag*/) as? UILabel {
    lbl.text = "some text"
}
```

Comment: i have declared 3 labels how do i find the exact one.

Comment: you will find out by the `tag` that you set for `UILabel`, see the edit